# How to return a HTML file as the response to a POST request?

Tags: php

I send a POST request to a PHP page, and depending on what the contents are I want it to return one of two independent HTML pages I have written.

Comment: Please show some code. Where are you sending a POST request? From the page? In JavaScript? In PHP? Using what function / library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if ($_POST['param'] == 'page1' )
    readfile('page1.html');
else
    readfile('other.html');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the page you want to return:

```
include( 'mypage.html' );
```

Comment: PHP can include many file types. An included file can just as easily be an HTML document - it doesn't have to be renamed.

Answer (score 2):

it's easy

```
<?php
 if($_POST['somevalue'] == true){
  include 'page1.html';
 }else{
  include 'page2.html';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just include the relevant page

```
 $someVar = $_POST['somevar'];
 if ($someVar == xxxxx)
    include "page1.htm";
 else
    include "page2.htm";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to directly implement this. You will need to examine the data POSTed to your PHP script and determine which of the two HTML documents to render.

```
<?php

    if (<your logical condition here>) {
        include 'DocumentOne.html';
    } else {
        include 'DocumentTwo.html';
    }

?>
```

This will work but is not ideal when POSTing data - any page reload will require the data to be POSTed again. This may cause underiable effects (is your action idempotent?).

A more suitable option is to use one PHP script to determine the output to use and then redirect the browser to the appropriate content. Once the user's browser has been redirected a page refresh will cleanly reload the page without any immediate adverse effects.

```
<?php

    if (<your logical condition here> {
        header('Location: http://example.com/DocumentOne.html');
    } else {
        header('Location: http://example.com/DocumentTwo.html');
    }

?>
```