# HTML file as the response to a POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, xmlhttprequest

I have seen questions and answers regarding this issue. For example [How to return a HTML file as the response to a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105124/how-to-return-a-html-file-as-the-response-to-a-post-request) but am having problems implementing the solutions. Here is a sample of some php code in a directory called websiteIssue that does not work, and I am not sure why.

index.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['page']))
{
     $page = $_POST['page'];
}
else
{
     $page = "";
}

include 'case.php';
?>
```

case.php

```
<?php
$testLog = 'testLog.txt';

$fileHandle = fopen('testLog.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fileHandle, '$page = '.$page."\n";

switch($page)
{
     case "screen2":
          include 'screen2.php';
          fwrite($fileHandle, 'including screen2.php'."\n");
          break;
     default:
          include 'screen1.php';
          fwrite($fileHandle, 'including screen1.php'."\n");
          break;
}
fclose($fileHandle);
?>
```

screen1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <title>screen1.php</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

     </head>

     <body>
          <button type="button" onClick=dataSubmit({page:"screen2"})> Screen 1 => Screen2</button>

          <script>
               function dataSubmit(data)
               {
                    var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var formData= new FormData();

                    for(name in data)
                    {
                         formData.append(name, data[name]);
                    }

                    xmlRequest.open('POST', 'http://localhost/websiteIssue/');
                    xmlRequest.send(formData);           
               }
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

screen2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <title>screen2.php</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

     </head>

     <body>
          <button type="button" onClick=dataSubmit({page:"screen1"})> Screen 2 => Screen1</button>

          <script>
               function dataSubmit(data)
               {
                    var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var formData= new FormData();

                    for(name in data)
                    {
                         formData.append(name, data[name]);
                    }

                    xmlRequest.open('POST', 'http://localhost/websiteIssue/');
                    xmlRequest.send(formData);           
               }
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

On initial load it works as I expected, the html in screen1.php is shown in the browser, but when the button on the page is pressed the html remains the same, rather than changing to that in screen2.php

The output to testText.log is something like:

```
$page = 
including screen1.php
$page = screen2
including screen2.php
```

As is might be obvious, I am a newbie to this, and hopefully there is some basic thing I have not done. The browser I am running it on is Firefox. Any help would be much appreciated.

Small note:I retyped the code by hand for this post, and have not run it (the machine running the webserver is not connected to the internet), hopefully there are no syntax errors, but I may have made a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

By including the php file you are responding to the javascript, but you arent actually using that response for anything. If redirecting to that page is what you want, you need to use *location.assign* on the response. To do that:

```
function dataSubmit(data)
{
    var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData= new FormData();

    // Redirects user to response when received.
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange=function{
        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) {
             location.assign(xmlRequest.responseText);
        }
    };

    for(name in data)
    {
         formData.append(name, data[name]);
    }

    xmlRequest.open('POST', 'http://localhost/websiteIssue/');
    xmlRequest.send(formData);           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I added the code you suggested (with the () after the word function) but found that I was getting an xmlRequest.status of 404 and the xmlRequest.responseText was html with <title>Object not found!</title>. Any ideas why that should be?

Comment: Sorry that was because of a mistake I made (I had slightly different code in case.php). Your suggestion works fine I just  added the brackets () after the function  (just mentioning in case anyone else wanted to try), and changed the includes in case.php to print. Just need to add appropriate code for $page to the screen php files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer given by Felipe Souza I made the following modifications to allow the page to be dynamically modified rather than being a redirect. Thought I would share as it is another solution which some might be interested in.

index.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['page']))
{
    $page = $_POST['page'];         
    include 'case.php';
}
else 
{
    include 'base.php';
}


?>
```

case.php

```
<?php

switch($page)
{
    case "screen2":
        include('screen2.php');
        break;
    case "screen1":
        include('screen1.php');
        break;
    default:
        include('screen1.php');
        break;  
}

?>
```

base.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>base.php</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <?php

            if(!isset($_POST['page']))
            {
                $page = "";
                include 'case.php';
            }
        ?>

        </div>

        <script>
         function dataSubmit(data)
         {

            var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var formData   = new FormData();

            xmlRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
            {

                if(xmlRequest.readyState==4 && xmlRequest.status==200)
                {   
                    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;           
                }

            }

            for(name in data)
            {
                formData.append(name, data[name]);
                console.log(name + ":" + data[name]);
            }

            xmlRequest.open('POST', 'http://localhost/websiteIssue/');
            xmlRequest.send(formData);

         }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

screen1.php

```
<button type"button" onClick=dataSubmit({page:"screen2"})> Screen 1 => Screen 2</button>
```

screen2.php

```
<button type"button" onClick=dataSubmit({page:"screen1"})>Screen 2 => Screen 1</button>
```

There seem some potential advantages in that the amount of data sent for the new screens is smaller, and (not sure if it is useful) the structure of the website is more disguised. Anyway, it is based on the answer given by Felipe Souza and supplements it (shows a dynamic approach rather than a changing pages one). Just thought I would mention it, if that was what some were looking for.